# CloudFoundry node-mongodb app always return 502

Tags: cloud-foundry

I followed steps provided by cloudfoundry guide page:
http://cndocs.cloudfoundry.com/services/mongodb/nodejs-mongodb.html
The first two steps are ok, both local and server works.
But when I add code to connect mongodb, it works in local, but in server, it just returns 502.
Anyone has clue？
my site is: http://daniel-mongo.cloudfoundry.com/

Answer (score 1):

have you taken a look at the logs for the application to see what might potentially be going wrong? You can view them by using the logs command in VMC.

Comment: thanks Dan, I checked the logs, and it says: TypeError: Property 'connect' of object #<Object> is not a function. Now I'm using mongodb node.js driver version 0.9.6-1. I'm new to node.js. Do you have any idea?

Comment: hi Dan, I've fixed this issue by update my mongodb driver JS version.